# boost serialization problem in windows vs2005, input stream error

Tags: c++, windows, serialization, boost

I am using boost serialization for serializing objects. In Linux all goes fine, but in Windows I am having problems deserializing data:

```
std::ifstream ifs(dataFilename.str().c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
{
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive persistenceFile(ifs);

    persistenceFile >> activeMessageAux;                
    persistenceFile >> activeMessageAux2;
}
```

And always fail on the second deserializing to activeMessageAux2, receiving a `boost::archive::archive_exception` input stream error. I can see that in the file I have all entrys that I suppose to have, so, I dont know why I'm having this exception. What could I do? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the entirety of the serialized data has been deserialized into `activeMessageAux`, why can't you just use normal assignment to populate `activeMessageAux2`?

```
std::ifstream ifs(dataFilename.str().c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
{
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive persistenceFile(ifs);
    persistenceFile >> activeMessageAux;                
}
activeMessageAux2 = activeMessageAux;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain it at all... in my persistence file, I have multiples objects stored. So, when I am making the second >> Im trying to get the object stored in the second position...

Comment: @opernas : It's been a couple years since I've used boost.serialization, but as I recall it doesn't work that way. If you want a single file to contain data for multiple serialized objects, you should serialize/deserialize a single array/std::vector of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The flag `std::ios::binary` is required only in Windows, where the default mode (ascii) would translate \n\r to \n (and vice versa), thus corrupting any data that is not textual.

Have you set it also in the export?

Comment: Im saving like this...

std::ofstream ofs(dataFilename.str().c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::app); boost::archive::binary_oarchive persistenceFile(ofs); persistenceFile << activeMessage;

So, perhaps i should remove ios::binary?

Comment: No - if it's binary in both places, then it's correct. The only thing that I see - you are appending every time. Is it possible some corrupted data existed because of development, and then it is just enough to delete the file once, in order to clean everything?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. Read an object, save the position with tellg and after that I can read the next object. :-D